# Redirect to custom url in webview ios 10

Tags: uiwebview, ios10

I want to load below URL in ios 10.

```
js2ios://%7B%22functionname%22:%22setTER%22,%22success%22:%22onSuccess%22,%22error%22:%22onError%22,%22args%22:%5B%22DohOa8bA5jbgbkhDLBOZXXRx5ecJQGDuqJvUeVVGdQFNDXYR8SZN+3Mn2A0RIYzgX4D67DdTmo32%5Cnwu4KUHcumJ0DMB6sSQRsNCqXtlYXtWGKVA93u5jr0oCOizD0KNTy97uAy9thaUGiQZHqp4pg2/+iP8cqzjQAnnTkaJXoOtPZy%5CnzqCZI9qIhJksPzjEQXyF9khqNLzHeQois6r7LkJbhm2ia0RFHVF5zRhtBYzdNijewt0+VDSWgArM%5CnsYCi2843EJfZ5fwIjXNmD/Tt2dZb2YsJTsTLGi9lJvsWQP/Ki/Uj7b57OWBWO6kyLNdvC2Z1ndtj%5CndrCF1BAHa68tqRfpJqyVOKGfiz36q6ahQjArDS+WlNPSqIReyPVKmviRrpTQgkvpLmj05Raqy4BK%5Cndr08/jrPJp4=%22,%22T3239%22%5D%7D
```

The same URL is working in till ios 9.3.
I have added below key in info.plist .But still not able to load the above URL

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>js2ios</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: Simulator not work can you try in device ?

Comment: On device also I have tested.It is not working.

Comment: Can you please post error log so i can identify.